# Python 3 Sockets - Receiving more then 1 character

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

So when I open up the CMD and create a telnet connection with:

telnet localhost 5555

It will apear a "Welcome", as you can see on the screen below.
After that every single character I type into the CMD will be printed out/send immediately.
My Question is: Is it, and if yes, how is it possible to type in messages and then send them so I receive them as 1 sentence and not char by char.
[image]

```
import socket
import sys
from _thread import *

host = ""
port = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((host,port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(5) #Enable a server to accept connections.
print("Waiting for a connection...")

def threaded_client(conn):
    conn.send(str.encode("Welcome\n"))

    while True:
    # for m in range (0,20): #Disconnects after x chars
        data = conn.recv(2048) #Receive data from the socket.
        reply = "Server output: "+ data.decode("utf-8")
        print(data)
        if not data:
            break
        conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
    conn.close()

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("connected to: "+addr[0]+":"+str(addr[1]))
    start_new_thread(threaded_client,(conn,))
```

Comment: Setting telnet in `^]mode line` should make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep reading until the stream ends:

```
string = ""

while True:
# for m in range (0,20): #Disconnects after x chars
    data = conn.recv(1) #Receive data from the socket.

    if not data:
        reply = "Server output: "+ string
        conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
        break
    else:
        string += data.decode("utf-8")

conn.close()
```

By the way, using that method you'll read one char at a time. You may adapt it to the way your server is sending the data.

Comment: Thank you it worked fine, but how can I remove something from the "string" when I misstyped, because Python gets it as a new char which I try to send him?

Comment: I think you want to remove a character from the string when the client presses backspace. Is that right? A python socket server can handle keystrokes, so I don't think that would be possible.

Comment: Yeah with backspace. Isn´t it possible to look if the last typed in character is an backspace and then remove it from the "string"?
Aren´t there any functions to remove the last character of a variable?

Comment: You would have to send the backspace. So, to delete a character, you would have to press Backspace then Return, and in the code, check if a `\b` character has been received.

Comment: And how can I remove the lat character from the "string"-variable?
I know it from arrays, but how does it work for a variable?

Comment: `string = string[:-1]`

Comment: I am so sorry for my dumb question, but how should I ask for a backspace? 

     if data.decode("utf-8") == "\b": ?

Comment: No problem. By the way, please accept the answer that has solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want to run on character mode or line mode.
Presently your code is fine, but your windows telnet client runs in character mode. You could use putty to give it a try in line mode, or if you really need to run in char mode, then keep reading the buffer until a newline is sent.

Here is what the server says when I run your code :

```
Waiting for a connection...
connected to: 127.0.0.1:46738
b'Hello\r\n'
```

the telnet session beeing :

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 5555
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Welcome
Hello
Server output: Hello
```

Comment: So it is actually a problem of the windows telnet client or what do you mean?

Comment: It's not really a problem, it is the way it's configured. try `ctrl altgr ]` `mode ?`  in your telnet session. it should output `^]mode ?`, and gives some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like: (pseudo code)

```
temp = conn.recv(2048)
data.concatenate(temp) # maybe data = data + temp ???? little rusty
if data[-1] == '\n':
    print 'message: ' + data
etc...
```

Comment: my bad didn't see previous answer. it is better.